# Accessing element from indexQuery, through titan-server

Tags: titan, gremlin

I wish to get the vertices ids when doing a indexQuery through the titanServer remotely. How can this be achieved? The documentation shows how to do this directly through gremlin.

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/server.html

```
ManagementSystem mgmt = graph.openManagement();
PropertyKey text = mgmt.makePropertyKey("text").dataType(String.class).make();
mgmt.buildIndex("vertexByText", Vertex.class).addKey(text).buildMixedIndex("search");
mgmt.commit();
// ... Load vertices ...
for (Result<Vertex> result : graph.indexQuery("vertexByText", "v.text:(farm uncle berry)").vertices()) {
   System.out.println(result.getElement() + ": " + result.getScore());
}
```

How could I do this remotely through gremlin-server?

How can I iterate through these and get the verticies ids?

```
gremlin> :> graph.indexQuery("user-description", "v.description:(BSc Hons Zoology. TEFL. Emotional)").vertices()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@2a11abb7
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@27b5bcae
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@315e9e70
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@4f40c549
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@68ab8305
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@62f11272
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@2799ad42
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@6e3a5e75
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.query.graph.IndexQueryBuilder$ResultImpl@5abd4b1c
```

Comment: Can you please share the remote configuration file you used when you connected the console to Gremlin Server?

Comment: We are using easticsearch and cassandra  gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory
storage.backend=cassandra
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1

cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.25

index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true

Comment: no - not your titan configuration.  when you issue the `:remote` command in the console, you have to give it a configuration file to connect.  what is in that file?

Comment: I've realised that I can do a full text searches with textContains instead